# PHP something wrong with my date validation

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I'm trying to validate a date in an input type="date" in d-m-Y format. The date cannot be higher than today.
I'm converting the difference in numbers and then ask if the number is less than 0.

Here's my validation function:

```
public static function validateDate($date){
    $dateToday = date_create(date('d-m-Y'));
    $datetime = date_create($date);
    if(date_diff($dateToday, $datetime)->format('%a') < 0){
        return false;
    }
    else{
        return true;
    }
}
```

The function doesn't work. the user can choose any date in the future and it goes right into the DB as YYYY-MM-DD.

I'm pretty lost here any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Start with debugging.

Comment: You can compare dates with comparison operators such as `<` or `>`. No need to do all this `date_diff` stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, this is probably a bad move:

```
$dateToday = date_create(date('d-m-Y'));
```

It's bad because both date and month have 2 digits.  While it may actually give you the result you expect, it looks counterintuitive to U.S. coders because dates are typcially written m-d-Y here. I would suggest `date("F j, Y")` which is a much clearer date format:

`var_dump(date("F j, Y")); // outputs "December 8, 2018"`

Second, you don't appear to do any validation on the $date parameter supplied to your function. It is presumably a string in d-m-Y format and you should enforce that with some validation.

Lastly, you the `%a` formatter you specify in this line just provides the digits of the date difference...it doesn't specify whether that is a *positive* difference or a *negative* difference.:

```
if(date_diff($dateToday, $datetime)->format('%a') < 0){
    //blah blah blah
}
```

You would need to include the `%R` format flag too to get the +/- of the difference:

```
if(date_diff($dateToday, $datetime)->format('%R%a') < 0){
    //blah blah blah
}
```

And finally, as of PHP 5.2.2., you can just compare the date objects created using a comparison operator. This is better than your code which compares a string to zero. Try this function:

```
public static function validateDate($date){
    if (!preg_match('/^\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}$/', $date)) {
            throw new Exception("$date is not a valid date in d-m-Y format");
    }
    $today = date_create(date("Y-m-d"));
    $datetime = date_create($date);

    if ($datetime > $today) {
            return false;
    } else {
            return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's really nice. I'm really new to Javascript and PHP but I can see it make a lot more sense than my function. More region-proof.

Comment: `$today = date_create('midnight')` (or `new \DateTime('midnight')` which is the equivalent) is another nifty way of doing that. Also, `return $datetime <= $today` can be done in a single line while you're at it.